# Using xpathSApply to scrape XML attributes in R

Tags: xml, r, xpath

I am scraping XML in R using xpathSApply (in the XML package) and having trouble pulling attributes out.

First, a relevant snippet of XML:

```
 <div class="offer-name">
        <a href="http://www.somesite.com" itemprop="name">Fancy Product</a>
      </div>
```

I have successfully pulled the 'Fancy Product' (i.e. element?) using:

```
Products <- xpathSApply(parsedHTML, "//div[@class='offer-name']", xmlValue)
```

That took some time (I'm a n00b), but the documentation is good and there are several answered questions here I was able to leverage. I can't figure out how to pull the "http://www.somesite.com" out though (attribute?). I've speculated that it involves changing the 3rd term from 'xmlValue' to 'xmlGetAttr' but I could be totally off.

FYI (1) There are 2 more parent < div> above the snippet I pasted and (2) here is the abbreviated complete-ish code (which I don't think is relevant but included for the sake of completeness) is:

```
library(XML)
library(httr)

content2 = paste(readLines(file.choose()), collapse = "\n") # User will select file.
parsedHTML = htmlParse(content2,asText=TRUE)

Products <- xpathSApply(parsedHTML, "//div[@class='offer-name']", xmlValue)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `href` is an attribute. You can select the appropriate node `//div/a` and use the `xmlGetAttr` function with `name = href`:

```
'<div class="offer-name">
  <a href="http://www.somesite.com" itemprop="name">Fancy Product</a>
  </div>' -> xData
library(XML)
parsedHTML <- xmlParse(xData)
Products <- xpathSApply(parsedHTML, "//div[@class='offer-name']", xmlValue) 
hrefs <- xpathSApply(parsedHTML, "//div/a", xmlGetAttr, 'href')
> hrefs
[1] "http://www.somesite.com"
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I chose this answer over jlhoward's as best for me because it's in the format I was using (doesn't mean it's better for all users) and the output hrefs could easily cbind as a single column. jlhoward's response resulted in an object that cbind as 2 columns (one was all href) so a bit more work.  Would +1 if I had the reputation.

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this directly using XPath, without using `xpathSApply(...)`.

```
xData <- '<div class="offer-name">
  <a href="http://www.somesite.com" itemprop="name">Fancy Product</a>
  </div>'
library(XML)
parsedHTML <- xmlParse(xData)
hrefs <- unlist(parsedHTML["//div[@class='offer-name']/a/@href"])
hrefs
#                      href 
# "http://www.somesite.com"
```

Comment: XML syntactic sugar +1

Comment: This works too and could be the better solution in other situations though I found the inclusion of 'href' with the URLs to make it a slightly less effective approach

Comment: href is NOT included with the urls! This returns a named vector. 'href' is the name.

Comment: Fair enough - my mistake, I'm still new and got an extra column when I used cbind() to combine the data I needed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I benchmarked it on a large file with 20000 numeric data to extract, and the version with  `xpathApply` was slower by a factor of 9.