# How to parse HTML/XML tags according to NOT conditions in [r]

Tags: html, r, xpath, xml-parsing

Dearest StackOverflow homies,

I'm playing with HTML that was output by EverNote and need to parse the following:

- Note Title
- Note anchor (hyperlink identities of the notes themselves)
- Note Creation Date
- Note Content, and
- Intra-notebook hyperlinks (the
  links within the content of a note to another note's anchor)

According to [examples by Duncan Temple Lang](http://www.omegahat.org/RSXML/shortIntro.html), author of the [r] XML package and a [SO answer by @jdharrison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25315381/using-xpathsapply-to-scrape-xml-attributes-in-r), I have been able to parse the Note Title, Note anchor, and Note Creation Dates with relative ease. For those who may be interested, the commands to do so are

```
require("XML")
rawHTML <- paste(readLines("EverNotebook.html"), collapse="\n") #Yes... this is noob code
doc = htmlTreeParse(rawHTML,useInternalNodes=T)
#Get Note Titles
html.titles<-xpathApply(doc, "//h1", xmlValue)
#Get Note Title Anchors
html.tAnchors<-xpathApply(doc, "//a[@name]", xmlGetAttr, "name")
#Get Note Creation Date
html.Dates<-xpathApply(doc, "//table[@bgcolor]/tr/td/i", xmlValue)
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9egf701o/) of an example HTML EverNote export.

I'm stuck on parsing **1. Note Contents** and **2. Intra-notebook hyperlinks**.

Taking a closer look at the code it is apparent the solution for the first part is to return every upper-most* div that **does NOT** include a table with attribute bgcolor="#D4DDE5." **How is this accomplished?**

Duncan says that it is possible to use XPath to parse XML according to NOT conditions:

> "It allows us to express things such as "find me all nodes named a" or "find me all nodes named a that have no attribute named b" or "nodes a that >have an attribute b equal to 'bob'" or "find me all nodes a which have c as >an ancestor node"

However he does not go on to describe how the XML package can parse exclusions... so I'm stuck there.

Addressing the second part, consider the format of anchors to other notes in the same notebook:

```
<a href="#13178">
```

The goal with these is to procure their number and yet this is difficult because they are solely distinguished from www links by the `#` prefix. Information on how to parse for these particular anchors via partial matching of their value (in this case `#`) is sparse - maybe even requiring grep(). **How can one use the XML package to parse for these special hrefs?** I describe both problems here since it's possible a solution to the first part may aid the second... but perhaps I'm wrong. **Any advice?**

**UPDATE 1**

By upper-most div I intend to say outer-most div. The contents of every note in an EverNote HMTL export are within the DOMs outer-most divs. Thus the interest is to **return every outer-most div that does NOT include a table with attribute bgcolor="#D4DDE5."**

Comment: Could you also add the desired result to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "....to return every upper-most div that does NOT include a table with attribute bgcolor="#D4DDE5." **How is this accomplished?**"

One possible way ignoring 'upper-most' as I don't know exactly how would you define it :

```
//div[not(table[@bgcolor='#D4DDE5'])]
```

Above XPath reads: select all `<div>` not having child element `<table>` with `bgcolor` attribute equals `#D4DDE5`.

I'm not sure about what you mean by "parse" in the 2nd part of the question. If you simply want to get all of those links having special `href`, you can partially match the `href` attribute using `starts-with()` or `contains()` :

```
//a[starts-with(@href, '#')]

//a[contains(@href, '#')]
```

**UPDATE :**

Taking "outer-most" div into consideration :

```
//div[not(table[@bgcolor='#D4DDE5']) and not(ancestor::div)]
```

Side note : <s>I don't know exactly how XPath `not()` is defined, but if it works like *negation* in general,</s> (this worked as confirmed by OP in the comment below) you can apply one of [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) :

> "not (A or B)" is the same as "(not A) and (not B)".

so that the updated XPath can be *slightly* simplified to :

```
//div[not(table[@bgcolor='#D4DDE5'] or ancestor::div)]
```

Comment: Your second suggestion for `xpathApply(doc, "//div[not(table[@bgcolor='#D4DDE5'])]", xmlValue)` is on the money. What I mean by _upper-most_ divs is that they are the greatest ancestor div. I strayed from calling them _root_ divs since that word has a narrow definition in the XML package meaning [only the top of the DOM](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/XML/docs/xmlRoot). Perhaps I should have called them outer-most divs... I will edit the post

Comment: **How would one proceed to get outer-most divs?** I'm thinking it involves matching every div tag who's `xmlParent()` operation returns a `body` tag.

Comment: @zelusp I'm not sure about `r`'s specific solution, but xpath expression to get `<div>` without ancestor `<div>` is like so : `//div[not(ancestor::div)]`

Comment: @zelusp check **UPDATE** section

Comment: `> identical(html.notesExpanded,html.notesSimplified)
[1] TRUE`

Comment: Anyone doing work with xpathApply is strongly encouraged to check the [XPath Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)