# How to pick up date from this HTML using xpathSApply in R

Tags: r, xml, xpath

I want to pick up the "data" part—`data-datetime="27 May 2016"`—from this HTML:

```html
<div class="date date--v2 relative-time" data-seconds="1464367034" data-datetime="27 May 2016" data-timestamp-inserted="true">3 hours ago
</div>
```

I want to use R XML package command xpathSApply to do this though I am not able to figure out the path that I should specify to get the value `27 May 2016` of the attribute `data-datetime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in using the rvest package, here is a possible solution:

```
#sample data
text<-'<div class="date date--v2 relative-time" data-seconds="1464367034" data-datetime="27 May 2016" data-timestamp-inserted="true">3 hours ago'

library(rvest)
#read page
page<-read_html(text)

#find nodes of interest
node<-xml_nodes(page, "div.date")
#extract out attr of interest
html_attr(node, "data-datetime")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//div[@class="date date--v2 relative-time"]/@data-datetime
```

Comment: On using this command `(xpathSApply(PARSED, "//div[@class='date date--v2 relative-time']/@data-datetime"))` , I get output as NULL

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help with your library but i'm sure in that Xpath

Comment: @user3205469 Look there, I think it will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25315381/using-xpathsapply-to-scrape-xml-attributes-in-r